# Batch/Windows Command Line - File compare then open chrome

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

In batch/windows CMD:
I know how to compare files and how to open chrome. 
Just how do I make an IF statement for these conditions?

If file1 == file2 -> dirToChrome.exe 
If file1 != file2 -> exit

EDIT: They are html files containing either a 0 or a 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on c-toesca's answer, here is the code:

```
:: These are parameters that are passed into the script 
set file1=%1
set file2=%2

:: Extracting the contents of the files
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%c in ('type "%file1%"') do set file1_value=%%c
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%c in ('type "%file2%"') do set file2_value=%%c

:: Comparing the values
IF "%file1_value%" EQU "%file2_value%" (
    dirToChrome.exe
) ELSE (
    exit
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is file1 and file2? (a hash of the files, a filename etc ?)

To compare 2 strings (file names, file hash for example):

```
set file1=%1
set file2=%2

IF %file1% EQU %file2% (
    dirToChrome.exe
)ELSE (
    exit
)
```